# Updating CloudKit record and get "UITextField.text must be used from main thread only"

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, xcode9

So when I select my record in tableview to the edit and save it will only save if I choose the record that does not give *"UITextField.text must be used from main thread only"*

This show the error and all 3 textfields are used the same all true.
[image: Showing the error]

Anybody got an idea?

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let predi = NSPredicate(format: "Feil = %@", self.txtFeilF.text!)

    Animation.isHidden = false
    Animation.startAnimating()

    let query2 = CKQuery(recordType: "Feilrapporter", predicate: predi)

    publicDataBase2.perform(query2, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error--->" + error.debugDescription)


        }else  {
            if (results?.count)! > 0 {

                let records = (results?[0])! as CKRecord

                records.setObject(self.txtNameF.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "RaportertAv")
                records.setObject(self.txtFeilF.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "Feil")
                records.setObject(self.txtFeilMsgF.text as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "Melding")

                self.publicDataBase2.save(records, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error--->" + error.debugDescription)
                    }else {
                        print("Endring Gjort")
                    }

                })
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

                self.Animation.stopAnimating()
                self.Animation.isHidden = true
                self.save.isEnabled = false

                self.present(self.alertSaveEditData, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.txtNameF.isHidden = true
                self.txtFeilF.isHidden = true
                self.txtFeilMsgF.isHidden = true

                self.txtFeilF.text = ""
                self.txtNameF.text = ""
                self.txtFeilMsgF.text = ""

                self.recFeil = ""
                self.recName = ""
                self.recMSG = ""
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The handler for the previous `perform` will execute on a background queue, so you are accessing the UI element on a queue other than the main queue.  Now, in theory, simply reading the property should be OK, but the new warning in Xcode 9 is alerting you to the fact that you have a potential problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that you are accessing UITextField on a different thread which would not work. So before starting the perform method, you declare everything in variables and use it when needed.

Change to this:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let predi = NSPredicate(format: "Feil = %@", self.txtFeilF.text!)

    Animation.isHidden = false
    Animation.startAnimating()

    let query2 = CKQuery(recordType: "Feilrapporter", predicate: predi)

    let nameF = self.txtNameF.text as CKRecordValue?
    let feilF = self.txtFeilF.text as CKRecordValue?
    let feilMsgF = self.txtFeilMsgF.text as CKRecordValue?

    publicDataBase2.perform(query2, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error--->" + error.debugDescription)


        }else  {
            if (results?.count)! > 0 {

                let records = (results?[0])! as CKRecord

                records.setObject(nameF, forKey: "RaportertAv")
                records.setObject(feilF, forKey: "Feil")
                records.setObject(feilMsgF, forKey: "Melding")

                self.publicDataBase2.save(records, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error--->" + error.debugDescription)
                    }else {
                        print("Endring Gjort")
                    }

                })
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

                self.Animation.stopAnimating()
                self.Animation.isHidden = true
                self.save.isEnabled = false

                self.present(self.alertSaveEditData, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.txtNameF.isHidden = true
                self.txtFeilF.isHidden = true
                self.txtFeilMsgF.isHidden = true

                self.txtFeilF.text = ""
                self.txtNameF.text = ""
                self.txtFeilMsgF.text = ""

                self.recFeil = ""
                self.recName = ""
                self.recMSG = ""
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. But still got the issue of not the record not saving. No longer have textfield issue.

Comment: That is another question, unrelated to your initial question. 
Why is it not saving? Do you get an error or what's going on ?

Comment: I thought it was related since when I only edit the field called textNameF.text it will save, but when all or the other two is filled it does nothing except show "alertSaveEditData"

Comment: It only seem to wanna save only what I change     `let predi = NSPredicate(format: "RaportertAv = %@", self.txtNameF.text!)` to